# EntityFramework: Code First Model with Methods

Tags: ef-code-first

Simple question, Lets say you are creating a code first database. Is it okay to put methods in your Model? I don't want the database to have procedures or functions for these methods though. So basically, all I want is to have my attributes mapped.

Comment: What happens when you have a method in code first and update the database?

Comment: It creates the table and everything seems to work fine. Also, I don't see any strange procedure on the database side. However, I'm not sure if its a safe way of doing things.